# How many leading principal minors are there for a $4 \times 4$ matrix?

Tags: matrices, determinant

> How many leading principal minors are there for a $4 \times 4$ matrix?

Please explain in detail. I know for a $3 \times 3$ matrix.

Comment: What do you know about the meaning of *leading*, *principal*, and *minor*?

Comment: i know for a 3X3 matrix leading principal minors are a11, a11*a22-a12*a21, det of original matrix.

Comment: Imagine the tabular form of the $3\times3$ matrix and draw three box frames around the elements used in its three leading principal minors, then you will recognize the scheme.

Comment: So u mean there will be a total of four leading minors... a11, a11*a22-a12*a21, a11*((a22 * a33) - (a23*a32)) - a12*((a21*a33) - (a23*a31)) + a13*((a21*a32) - (a22*a31)), determinant of the  original matrix... ???

Comment: Yes!! Now guess, what might an example for a *non-leading* principal minor be?

Comment: All the other possible determinant.

Comment: Not all, just the *principal* ones: those that use the same rows as columns. Not something in the upper-right corner, for example. Those are the *principal* minors. With neither *principal* nor *leading*, all possible sub-determinants are allowed indeed.

Comment: Consider adding an official answer yourself, as you have found it now.

Comment: it consists of matrix elements in rows and columns from 1 to k), then the principal minor is called a leading principal minor. For an n × n square matrix, there are n leading principal minors.

Answer (score 0):

The kth order leading principal minor is the determinant of the kth order principal
submatrix formed by deleting the last n − k rows and columns.

Answer (score 0):

the first order leading principal minors is a11.
the second order leading principal minors is a11*a22-a21*a12.
the third order leading principal minors is  the determinant of the original matrix after deleting the last rows and columns.
the first order leading principal minors is determinant of the original matrix A.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are referring to leading principal submatrix rather than leading principal minors, which is a bit broad. If you can find for 3*3 matrix and you know how to do it, you can use the same method to find for 4*4 matrix.